# Script to get detached databases from folder and subfolders

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Is there a way to find out if SQL Server databases are attached from a directory with many subfolders apart from going to properties of each .mdf and checking if it is attached?

Is there a script that can check folders/subfolders an write to file to accomplish this?

THanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you need to read the file system from T-SQL, I find that CLRs have the most flexibility. They give you full access to the system.io namespace as well as support for table valued functions.

Have a look at the [SQL Server CLR IO Utility](http://www.wisesoft.co.uk/articles/sql_server_clr_io_utility.aspx). There is a full solution here which enables filesystem functionality that is not easily available with the [frowned upon](http://www.iderware.com/sql-security-disable-sql-xp_cmdshell) xp_cmdshell.

The table valued function, SQLIO_fnGetFiles, can be used to join to the sys.master_files table and return files which are no longer attached to a database. In this example, the CLR is deployed to a database named CLRS:

```
USE master

SELECT fs.PATH FileSystemPath
     , FileIsAttached = CASE WHEN d.name IS NULL THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END
     , d.name DatabaseName
     , mf.name FileLogicalName
     , mf.physical_name DatabaseFilePath
     , FileType = CASE mf.type_desc WHEN 'ROWS' THEN 'DATA' ELSE mf.type_desc END

FROM CLRS.dbo.SQLIO_fnGetFiles('L:\MSSQL\','*df',1) fs
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.master_files mf ON fs.PATH = mf.physical_name
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.databases d ON d.database_id = mf.database_id
```

There are also other methods (powershell, .net, ssis,...) to accomplish this. My experience is that once you deploy the IO Utility solution, you'll find many other time saving uses for it.

Comment: Thanks ever so much brian. Is there a way of ignoring folders if there is any access issues e.g. folders permission issues...i get the following: `A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "SQLIO_fnGetFiles": 
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '\\TestDest\MyFolder\Test\' `

Comment: It sounds like the service account running the database engine doesn't have read permission to the share/folder. If that's the case, there's most likely no attached database files in that share/folder...

Comment: Great to hear! This solution will allow you to insert the results into a table. If you still want to write the output to a file though, you can use the stored procedures SQLIO_CreateTextFile and SQLIO_AppendTextFile to do this.

Answer (score 1):

This should be fairly easy to do:

firstly i would query the database server sysdatabase table to locate all databases you have attached and there corresponding file names and store in a temporary table.

Using the xp_cmdshell function exec a dos DIR command to list all MDF/LDF files with the right switch to navigate folders and store the results in another temporary table

Compare these tables and you will be able to find what files are not attached.

I have done similar tasks before and used both SSIS and Direct Transact-SQL

T

Comment: Thanks Terry. I will keep xp_cmdshell function in mind for future.